# ndimage is not in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, python-import

I tried to import `ndimage` package from `SciPy` to use the maximum filter in it. However, it seems `SciPy` is missing this part. I got this error:

```
from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I even tried these as well (separately):

```
import scipy.ndimage 
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter
import ndimage form scipy
```

But I still get the **same** error.

The complete error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Programs\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Users\Programs\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Programs\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/Test_2/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from .filters import *
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 37, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import doccer
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 20, in <module>
    import scipy.linalg
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 186, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 196, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: What's this give you?  `import scipy` --> `scipy.__version__`.

Comment: It gave me `1.0.0`

Comment: How did you install SciPy? (please mention origin of the package, type of download (wheel, source, etc). How did you install Python (download from python.org, other?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried two methods and they helped me to solve this problem:

1- Uninstall `SciPy` and `NumPy` and reinstall them again,

2- If you are using `SciPy 1.0.0`, downgrade it to a previous version (e.g. I downgraded it to `SciPy 0.19.1`). This one was suggested by @Brad Solomon

I'm sure one of these is the solution!